# Open API 2 with Spring Boot does not return HTTP 400 for a param value outside declared enum values

Tags: spring-boot, rest, swagger-2.0

I have REST API for e.g. `/v1/vehicles/{color}/{make}/{modelno}`

I used OpenAPi 2.0 for this. I made color as enum with 3 values (black, white, gray). Make is also enum with values like (Suzuki, Toyota, Honda) and modelno is regex pattern.

When I call the api with for e.g. `/v1/vehicles/abc/suzuki/alto1999`, it gives me the expected HTTP400 Bad request. This is the intension.

**However** I call the api with for e.g. `/v1/vehicles/gray/suzuki/blabla` or `/v1/vehicles/gray/blabla/alto1999`, then I get a Error 500. That is if I enter any value for the **second** or the **third** path param, the call actually goes to the controller, reaches the service where the Error 500 occurs. It does not get handled like the first param.  This is crazy. It should have been handled by Spring.

Can anybody help me understand this please?

Sorry I cannot share code, its on the confidential server.

Comment: What is the exception that's triggering the 500 response?

Comment: I believe any exception occuring at runtime would result in 5xx Error. You may validate and send your own custom response if the parse fails or the passed Path variable value is not defined in Enum.